# Filter RecylerView on the basis of Model

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview, fastadapter

Filter RecyclerView on the basis of model using FastAdapter

```
open class StoreModeBaseModel -> ParentClass
```

Child Classes

```
data class PersonalOfferModel(val personalOffer: PersonalOffer) : StoreModeBaseModel()
data class FavoriteOfferModel(val product: Product) : StoreModeBaseModel()
```

I am using fast Adapter like

```
private val itemAdapter = ModelAdapter { element: StoreModeBaseModel ->
        getItem(element)
    }

private fun getItem(element: StoreModeBaseModel): GenericItem {
        return when (element) {
           
            is PersonalOfferModel -> PersonalOfferItemStoreMode(element)
            is FavoriteOfferModel -> FavoriteOfferItem(element).apply {
                this.model.product.forSaleOnline = false
            }
            else -> FooterItem(element)
        }
    }
```

I am setting data like

```
                personalOffersList.map { models.add(PersonalOfferModel(it)) }
                favoriteOffersList.map { models.add(FavoriteOfferModel(Product.mapFromDB(it))) }

                if (itemAdapter.models.isEmpty()) {
                    itemAdapter.clear()
                    itemAdapter.add(models)
                } else {
                    itemAdapter.set(models)
                }
```

> Now on click of a tab or button I want to filter PersonalOffer and FavouriteOffer

When I click on **PersonalOffer** tab models with **PersonalOfferModel** should be shown in `RecyclerView` and when I select(click) on FavoriteOffer then `FavoriteOfferModel` items should be shown in **RecyclerView**